# remove series by name or id in highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Is there anyway to remove a series by name or id? I mean it is possible to remove series by `this.remove()`

or

```
var seriesLength = chart.series.length;
for(var i = seriesLength - 1; i > -1; i--) {
    chart.series[i].remove();
}
```

but by name say, `series_name.remove()` is it possible?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ok, I found it myself. I send the series name in a hidden field of a div and when I click the delete button I'm checking if the name matches among the series and if match found I delete it.

```
var chart = $('#container').highcharts();
                var seriesLength = chart.series.length;
                for(var i = seriesLength - 1; i > -1; i--)
                {
                    //chart.series[i].remove();
                    if(chart.series[i].name ==document.getElementById("series_name").value)
                        chart.series[i].remove();
                }
```

Answer (score 19):

Well, I don't know if at the time it was possible, but now you have a `get` function in the `chart` object to which you can pass an `id` and retrieve an element within the `chart`.

For example:

```
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({    
    chart: { renderTo: 'container' },
    series: [
      {
        id: 'series-1', 
        data: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
      },
      {
        id: 'series-2',
        data: [9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1]
      }
    ]
});

//Remove the 'series-2'
chart.get('series-2').remove();
```

[Working example in jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lcguida/Ltdam8cp/2/)

Answer (score 1):

This needs more visibility, because this is fairly janky.  You could probably just iterate through the series and check the .name against your "passed in name" instead of scanning the document for "series_name".

There really should be a chart.remove(series) (not just index, because the indices remap after you remove one).

Answer (score 1):

These two simple solutions work for me.

UPDATE : I realized I misunderstood the question. These solutions remove all the ledends.

#### Hide it using jQuery

```
$(function () {
  // Build the chart.
  $('#volume_pie_chart').highcharts({
      // Some configuration code...
    })

    // Hide the legend.
    $('.highcharts-legend').hide()
});
```

#### Position the legend so that we do not see it

```
...
},
legend: {
    x: 9999, // Make the legend invisible.
    y: 9999
},
...
```

Answer (score 0):

**HighCharts 6.x.x**

You can get the Series object by Id using `Chart::get` method. Heres the link for documentation - https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Chart#get

Also Series has a `remove` method to remove the series from the chart - https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Series#remove